# Data conversion from Varchar to Date SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `SourceTable` which contains two columns `First_Sale_Date` and `Last_Sale_Date` and both are of data type `varchar(10)`. The `First_Sale_Date` column contains date(mm/dd/yyyy format) and the `Last_Sale_Date` contain nothing.

I need to load `SourceTable` data to Table 2 with same column(columns `First_Sale_Date` and `Last_Sale_Date`) but in `Table2` both columns are of `date` data type. the problem is when i load the data to `Table2` from `SourceTable`, the first column is loaded as converted date format but in the second column values shown as `NULL` . I want the `Table2` to be empty if there are no records in `SourceTable`

Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Date can't be an empty string. It can be NULL or a date.

Comment: I have read this several times and don't quite understand what you mean. Are you saying you don't want NULL when there is no data in Source_Table for Last_Sale_Date? If I understand you correctly you don't want NULL but instead want an empty string??? An empty string when converted to a date is 1900-01-01. Trust me on this one...you want it to be NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much Roland and Sean. I understood what you told